# COMO GUARDAR UN VALOR DE HORA EN UNA TABLA EN MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Me gustaría que me ayudaran en lo siguiente ya que soy novato en esto de Mysql y Php. Estoy haciendo una tabla de asistencia y tengo una fecha de entrada y una fecha en la cual la persona debe llegar puntual o sino me aparece los minutos de retardo. Realice la formula de mysql y me esta dando el valor de la resta de la hora de llegada y la hora en la que debe entrar. Ese valor que me arroja deseo guardarlo en una tabla en la base de dato para tenerlo guardado y poderlo usar para otras cosas, pero no se como hacerlo. Adjunto el código y adjunto imagen del valor que me da.

El valor del tiempo que esta encerrado en el circulo rojo es el que deseo guardar en una tabla de la base de datos en mysql. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php           
            
                  $sql = "SELECT *, TIME_FORMAT(TIME(TIMEDIFF(attendance.time_in,schedules.time_in)),'%H:%i') as minutos,

                          employees.employee_id AS empid, 
                          attendance.id AS attid, 
                          employees.position_id AS empid2, 
                          position.id AS posid,
                          employees.tropa_id AS empid3,
                          tropa.id AS troid,
                          attendance.time_in AS troid50,
                          schedules.time_in AS scheid
                        /*  (((schedules.time_in - attendance.time_in)/60/60),2) AS resultado */
                        /*  schedules.id AS scheid*/                        

                    FROM attendance 
                    LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.id=attendance.employee_id
                    LEFT JOIN position  ON employees.position_id=position.id
                    LEFT JOIN tropa  ON employees.tropa_id=tropa.id
                 /*   LEFT JOIN schedules  ON schedules.time_in=schedules.id*/
                 LEFT JOIN schedules ON schedules.id=employees.schedule_id

                /* WHERE (((schedules.time_in - attendance.time_in)/60/60),2) AS resultado*/                    
                    ORDER BY attendance.date DESC, attendance.time_in DESC";

               
                    $query = $conn->query($sql);
                    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                      $status = ($row['status'])?'<span class="label label-warning pull-right">a tiempo</span>':'<span class="label label-danger pull-right">tarde</span>';
                      $status10 = ($row['status'])?'<span class="label label-primary pull-right">No Descuento</span>':'<span class="label label-danger pull-right">Descontar</span>';
                     /* $status2 = ($row['status'])?'<span class="label label-primary pull-right">No Justificado</span>':'<span class="label label-danger pull-right">Justificado</span>';*/
                      echo "
                        <tr>
                          <td class='hidden'></td>
                          <td>".date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['date']))."</td>
                        <!--  <td>".$row['empid']."</td>-->
                          <td>".$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['identificacion']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['description']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['description2']."</td>

                       <!--   <td>".$row['time_in']."</td>-->

                          <!-- HORARIO DE REGISTRO-->
                          <td>".date('h:i A', strtotime($row['troid50'])).$status."</td>

                        <!--  <td>".$row['scheid']."</td> --> <!-- HORARIO DE ENTRADA-->
                          <td>".date('h:i A', strtotime($row['scheid']))."</td>

              
                          <!-- TIEMPO A DESCONTAR-->
                          
                          <td>".$row['minutos'].$status10."</td>

                          <td align='center'>".$row['justificacion'].$status2."</td>
                          
                        <!--  <td>".date('h:i A', strtotime($row['time_out']))."</td>-->
                          <td>

                            <button class='btn btn-success btn-sm btn-flat edit' data-id='".$row['attid']."'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Editar</button>
                            <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-flat delete' data-id='".$row['attid']."'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Eliminar</button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
                                            
                    }
                   
                  ?>
```

Comment: No es una buena idea guardar campos calculados en las tablas. ¿Por qué no los calculas por programación cuando lo necesites, siendo que ya tienes en la tabla los datos importantes que son la fecha/hora en que debe llegar y la fecha/hora en que llegó? Guardar también un dato calculado en torno a eso no sólo es redundante, sino que podrías estar creando un cementario de datos calculados solamente por si acaso los necesitarás algún día. No es una buena práctica, a no ser que haya algún motivo que justifique hacer eso.

Comment: Gracias, A. Cedano, pues este dato si lo necesitaría conservarlo para poder luego sacar un reporte y poder sumar las fechas/hora de retardos para poder saber cuanto tiempo llego tarde una persona en el mes, semana, quincena.

Comment: Pero eso lo puedes hacer por programación, el día que lo necesites, en vez de tener durmiendo en tu tabla miles o millones de datos para usarlos eventualmente. Quizá esos datos, pasado un año, no tendrán interés y estarán ahí, durmiendo en tu base de datos sin ninguna utlidad. A eso me refería con el término *cementario de datos*. Ese es uno de los motivos, entre otros, por los que no conviene guardar datos calculados en las tablas, a no ser que haya una razón que lo justifique, como que esos datos se usen constantemente, diariamente, de forma concurrente por varios miles/millones de usuarios.

Comment: ok, y como soy novato en estas cosas como se podría hacer por programación como una orientación con respecto a esto. Gracias

Comment: Puedes usar las funciones propias de MySQL o de PHP para calcular la diferencia de tiempo en base a los datos ya existentes en la tabla como hora en que debía llegar y hora real de llegada. En ambos programas hay múltiples funciones para ello. Otro error que veo en tu tabla es tener por un lado la fecha y por otro la hora. Eso se podría complicar muy fácilmente con algo tan simple como que en la empresa haya turnos que empiecen un día y terminen otro. Supongamos un turno de 11 de la noche a 5 de la mañana del otro día. Esa simpleza rompería tu diseño. Es mejor tener dos columnas ...

Comment: ... del tipo `DATETIME` donde almacenarías **la fecha y hora de llegada**  y la **fecha y hora de salida**. Así, registrarías ambos datos completos en una sola columna y podrías manejar turnos que cabalguen entre dos fechas sin ningún problema. Y esos mismos datos se podrían usar para hacer los cálculos que sean necesarios.